# Accelerometer in my android coding

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have created two set of class heres one class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TicTacToeTutorial extends Activity {

private TicTacToeGame mGame;

private Button mBoardButtons[];

private TextView mInfoTextView;
private TextView mHumanCount;
private TextView mTieCount;
private TextView mAndroidCount;

private int mHumanCounter = 0;
private int mTieCounter = 0;
private int mAndroidCounter = 0;

private boolean mHumanFirst = true;
private boolean mGameOver = false;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
    mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
    mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

    mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
    mHumanCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humanCount);
    mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
    mAndroidCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);

    mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
    mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
    mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));

    mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

    startNewGame();

}

private void startNewGame()
{
    mGame.clearBoard();

    for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++) {
        mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
        mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);
        mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
    }



    if (mHumanFirst)
    {
        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.first_human);
        mHumanFirst = false;
    }
    else
    {
        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
        int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
        setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
        mHumanFirst = true;
    }
}

private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    int location;

    public ButtonClickListener(int location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (!mGameOver)
        {
            if (mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
            {
                setMove(mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);

                int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                if (winner == 0)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                    int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                    setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
                    winner = mGame.checkForWinner();
                }

                if (winner == 0)
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                else if (winner == 1)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                    mTieCounter++;
                    mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                    mGameOver = true;
                }
                else if (winner == 2)
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                    mHumanCounter++;
                    mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                    mGameOver = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                    mAndroidCounter++;
                    mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                    mGameOver = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void setMove(char player, int location)
{
    mGame.setMove(player, location);
    mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
    mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
    if (player == mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER)
        mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    else
        mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
}
}
```

heres the second part:

```
public TicTacToeGame() {

    mBoard = new char[BOARD_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;

    mRand = new Random();
}

public void clearBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;
    }
}

public void setMove(char player, int location) {
    mBoard[location] = player;
}

public int getComputerMove() {
    int move;

    for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++) {
        if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER) {
            char curr = mBoard[i];
            mBoard[i] = ANDROID_PLAYER;
            if (checkForWinner() == 3) {
                setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, i);
                return i;
            } else
                mBoard[i] = curr;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++) {
        if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER) {
            char curr = mBoard[i];
            mBoard[i] = HUMAN_PLAYER;
            if (checkForWinner() == 2) {
                setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, i);
                return i;
            } else
                mBoard[i] = curr;
        }
    }

    do {
        move = mRand.nextInt(getBOARD_SIZE());
    } while (mBoard[move] == HUMAN_PLAYER || mBoard[move] == ANDROID_PLAYER);

    setMove(ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
    return move;
}

public int checkForWinner() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i += 3) {
        if (mBoard[i] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 1] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 2] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
            return 2;
        if (mBoard[i] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 1] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 2] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
            return 3;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        if (mBoard[i] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 3] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 6] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
            return 2;
        if (mBoard[i] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 3] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                mBoard[i + 6] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
            return 3;
    }

    if ((mBoard[0] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[4] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[8] == HUMAN_PLAYER) ||
            mBoard[2] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                    mBoard[4] == HUMAN_PLAYER &&
                    mBoard[6] == HUMAN_PLAYER)
        return 2;
    if ((mBoard[0] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[4] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
            mBoard[8] == ANDROID_PLAYER) ||
            mBoard[2] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                    mBoard[4] == ANDROID_PLAYER &&
                    mBoard[6] == ANDROID_PLAYER)
        return 3;

for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++) {
        if (mBoard[i] != HUMAN_PLAYER && mBoard[i] != ANDROID_PLAYER)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;

}
}
```

I would like to add accelerometer to this code its part of my project for school I would like everyone  help thanks and also I am a beginner at android coding im trying if you see any errors let me know.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service, so you need to atleast try to do it by yourself. Then when you stuck at something, you can ask a question for that.

Comment: Android accelerometer is pretty easy to use, have you try to implement it? start with a tutorial, here there is a simple one https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/sensor/android-accelerometer-example/

Comment: I try to implement it but doesn't work can you help me

Comment: If u want to change on touch listener to motion sensor accelerometer how do I do that